# Unable to call an Objective C class delegate from a Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, delegates, protocols

My issue here is that I need the "protocolMethod" in the OldViewController.m to be called from the NewViewController.swift in a delegate fashion.

The project I'm working on was completely written in Objective C, and there's a new View Controller that was written in Swift.

The new View Controller is supposed to call a delegate method, conformed by the Objective C caller object, so the Objective C View Controller can process that call.

The app runs and the delegate is called from Swift, but never actually executed in the Objective C View Controller.

I've tried including all the sample files and the code that's supposed to be called, so here it is:

**MyProtocol.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)protocolMethod:(NSString*)input;

@end
```

**My-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#ifndef My_Bridging_Header_h

#define My_Bridging_Header_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "OldViewController.h"

#import "MyProtocol.h"

#endif
```

**OldViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OldViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**OldViewController.m**

```
@interface OldViewController ()<MyProtocol>

@end

 
@implementation OldViewController

 
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM: NEVER GETS CALLED

- (void)protocolMethod:(NSString *)input {

    NSLog(@"protocolMethod:%@", input);

}

 

- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

                NewViewController *newViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];

                [newViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

                [self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

 

}

@end
```

**NewViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc weak var myProtocol: MyProtocol?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.myProtocol?.protocolMethod("testing 123")

    }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where do you set the protocol ?

Comment: if <MyProtocol> is only in .m file, the header doesnt expose the protocol knowledge to swift. Your OldViewController.h file tells - no protocol here. and you have a typo in implementation name of LoginViewController

Comment: I've fixed the typos, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Call a `objective-C` protocol method in Objective-C class from Swift

define the protocol in Objective-c `MyProtocol.h`

```
#ifndef MyProtocol_h
#define MyProtocol_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)protoMethod:(NSString *)input;
@end

#endif
```

define interface of `LoginViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@class NewViewController; //declare knowledge of swift class
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol>
// method to trigger testing manual
-(void)haveFun;
@end
```

define implementation of `LoginViewController.m`

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "YourProductModulName-Swift.h" // will bridge exposed swift class to objc

@implementation LoginViewController
-(void)protoMethod:(NSString*)input {
     NSLog(@"protocolMethod:%@", input);
}
- (void)haveFun {
    // did not use the storyboard to make testing simple
    // this is an @objc exposed swift class
    NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    // now trigger predefined method that checks for protocol 
    [newViewController fun:self];
}
@end
```

now let us write a swift class that is subclassing an NSObject, here UIViewController and expose it to objc

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc //expose class when you need to use it from Objective-C
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    // as objc bridging is working with NSObjects,
    // we can use it instead of Any, which can't be exposed.
    @objc(foo) weak var foo : NSObject?
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // question was: how to call (id<MyProtocol>)-(void)protoMethod:
        // as we dont use storyboard for testing here..
        // nothing in here
    }
    
    // no autonaming, defined -(void)fun: instead
    @objc(fun:) func fun(protocolObj: MyProtocol) {
        let bar = protocolObj
        bar.protoMethod!("direct invokation of protoMethod")
        // ah why not, lets remember the object for later.
        foo = bar as? NSObject
        testme()
    }
    
    @objc func testme() {
        // as foo is NSObject here, check if exist
        if (foo != nil) {
            // cast foo and check for protocol
            if let loginview = foo as? MyProtocol {
                loginview.protoMethod!("PROTOCOL-LOL!")
            } else {
                print("i will allways love youuu!")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

now lets have some fun and use the back and forth bridged stuff.
This will allocate a Objective-c class `LoginViewController` following `<MyProtocol>` and invoke `-(void)haveFun` method. This method will allocate a Swift Class `NewViewController` (important! based on NSObject) that will invoke @objc exposed swift `func fun:` and give `self` as parameter that must follow the MyProtocol. It will then invoke the protocol method of LoginViewController with a parameter `NSString` and store the LoginViewController object in `weak var foo` as `NSObject`. Then it will trigger internal swift `testme()` and use the stored `foo` to check again if it exists and conforms to protocol MyProtocol and invokes the protocolMethod `-(void)protoMethod:(NSString*)string;` again or print something if not conforming.

```
LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[login haveFun];
```

Don't forget the example here needs Swift bridging to Objective-C and Objective-C bridging to Swift. If that is a perfect design pattern is another talk.

Comment: you could exchange "foo" with the word "delegate" and it does'nt actually have to be of type NSObject, MyProtocol is enough.

Comment: The answer to this was the line that assigned the Swift's local protocol variable to the Objective C "self". Now it makes sense where the Swift protocol variable gets its value (not magic). Here's the magical line: **[newViewController fun:self];**. You could also have the line be: **newViewController.myProtocol = self;**, which "loads" the Protocol implementation onto the Swift variable. Makes sense! Thank you for your efforts to help me with this. Great job!